# Can I rename a Windows failover cluster virtual network name AD object

Tags: active-directory, windows-cluster, rename

I have a new Windows 2019 Failover Cluster. I enabled the Automatic Cluster Aware Update feature, and this is functioning correctly.  It created a Computer object in AD called CAUBORG6cx.  Am I able to rename this (and others autocreated for other features), and if so, is it as simple as renaming in AD Users and Computers, or are there caveats to doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Braedon